# Update custom gridview from custom list adapter android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-custom-view

I have a listview that contains a set of a custom view. Inside each custom view is a gridview.

I want to be able to update the background of each cell in the gridview when the user clicks a checkbox in the custom view.

Here is my custom view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/lblHeaderCheckbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ca.package.CustomGridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    clickable="true" />
```

Here is my layout for each grid cell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridItem"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_itemTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how I fill the list

```
expListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.event_list);

    prepareListData();  

    listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, listDataHeader,
            listDataChild, listChildBoolean);

    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Here is the getView method in my custom adapter for the listView

```
public View getView(int groupPosition, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int gp = groupPosition;

    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    // Boolean bool = _listDataBoolean.get(groupPosition);
    Boolean bool = currentCalendarEvents.get(groupPosition).getAlert();

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    String[] data = new String[14];

    List<String> times = _currentListDataChild.get(_currentListDataHeader
            .get(groupPosition));

    data[0] = "Su";
    data[1] = "M";
    data[2] = "Tu";
    data[3] = "W";
    data[4] = "Th";
    data[5] = "F";
    data[6] = "Sa";

    data[7] = times.get(6); // sun
    data[8] = times.get(0); // mon
    data[9] = times.get(1); // tues
    data[10] = times.get(2); // wed
    data[11] = times.get(3); // thurs
    data[12] = times.get(4); // fri
    data[13] = times.get(5); // sat

    ArrayList<Boolean> boolArray = _listChildBoolean.get(_currentListDataHeader
            .get(groupPosition));

    final GridView gridView = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    final GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this._context, data, boolArray);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    final CheckBox chk2 = (CheckBox) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblHeaderCheckbox);
    chk2.setChecked(bool);

    chk2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chk2.isChecked()) {
                currentCalendarEvents.get(gp).setAlert(true);
                currentCalendarEvents.get(gp).setDaysTrue();

                // I WANT TO UPDATE THE LIST HERE

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "box checked");

            } else {
                currentCalendarEvents.get(gp).setAlert(false);
                currentCalendarEvents.get(gp).setDaysFalse();

                // AND HERE

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "box not checked");
            }
        }
    });


    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "gridview clicked");
            currentCalendarEvents.get(gp).setBoolDays(adapter.getHashMap());
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Here is my GridAdapter

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private String[] items;
private ArrayList<Boolean> boolArray;
private ArrayList<View> views;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public GridAdapter(Context context, String[] items,
        ArrayList<Boolean> boolArray) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.boolArray = boolArray;
    this.views = new ArrayList<View>();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, null);

        final TextView tv = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_itemTxt);
        tv.setText(items[position]);

        if (position < 7) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tv.setLines(2);
        } else {

            Log.e("blerp", "test : " + items[position]);

            if (!items[position].equals("")) {
                if (boolArray.get(position % 7)) {
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.LightGreen));
                } else {
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                }

                tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (boolArray.get(position % 7)) {
                            ((View) tv.getParent())
                                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                            boolArray.set(position % 7, false);
                        } else {
                            ((View) tv.getParent())
                                    .setBackgroundColor(context
                                            .getResources().getColor(
                                                    R.color.LightGreen));
                            boolArray.set(position % 7, true);
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
            tv.setLines(2);
        }

    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public HashMap<String,Boolean> getHashMap() {
    HashMap<String, Boolean> hm = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
    hm.put("sun", boolArray.get(0));
    hm.put("mon", boolArray.get(1));
    hm.put("tues", boolArray.get(2));
    hm.put("wed", boolArray.get(3));
    hm.put("thurs", boolArray.get(4));
    hm.put("fri", boolArray.get(5));
    hm.put("sat", boolArray.get(6));
    return hm;
}


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can post more of my code if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initiate gridview and checkbox in the adapter class (using find view by id).
then pass 
    if (checkBox.isChecked) {
gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(x,y,z)))}

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful and I am able to change the background of the entire gridview however I need to be able to change the background of each individual cell. Any ideas how I could go about that?

Comment: use convertView.setBac.... instead of gridview.setBac... in the if condition.  convertView represents 1 cell of a view.

Comment: convertView.setBac... will set the background of the whole custom view including the gridView. I need to set the background color of individual cells in the gridView withing the custom view.  I have tried gridView.getChildAt(i).setBac... but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: create a new viewholder for the contents of each cell to hold views of eachcell. then try setting the background color for the view that is hold my the viewholder that u defined